# Matrix Algebra Determinant: What's Wrong Here?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Trying to find det(ATA), and I get 313110. But, the online calculator says the answer is 4900. I can't see where I've gone wrong in my working, can anyone help?

[image]

A:

[image]

Comment: If you know $A$, it might be a lot easier to remark $\det(A^T A) = \det(A^T) \det(A) = \det(A)^2$. In particular, all you have to do is check $\det(A) = 70$.

Comment: I should note that det(A) = 70, yes, but I'm not familiar with that method @B.Mehta

Comment: @MathsHelp I've expanded on the method below. Does this help you understand?

Comment: @egreg just posted A

Comment: Messy handwriting, but it does say 55 @egreg

Comment: @egreg, I think that's just a poor quality picture - it looks close enough to $55$, and the calculation reaching $925$ in the next line required $55$, so not a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$A^TA$ appears correct. One error: Changing $2072$ to $2074$.

The other errors occur when you do row operations. For example, in your answer you replace $R1$ by $3R1 + 22R3$. If you replace $R1$ by $R1 + \frac{22}3R3$ (i.e., if you add a multiple of another row to $R1$), then the determinant is unchanged; but the move you've made requires that you carry a factor of $\frac13$ in front. Similarly if you replace $R2$ as you've done, you need to carry another factor of $\frac13$. In the end you'll need to adjust your answer by $\frac1{27}$ to obtain $4900$ as the determinant.

Comment: Thanks for that, fixed in my notes now.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my answer in the comments:

An easier way of doing this might be to observe
$$\det(A^T A) = \det(A^T) \det(A)$$
since determinant is multiplicative, and then that
$$\det(A^T) = \det(A)$$
since the determinant of a transpose is exactly the determinant. So, $\det(A^T A) = \det(A)^2$, which could well be easier to calculate.

---

The issue with your attempt is that your "row operations" weren't valid row operations. In particular, $R_1 \to 3R_1 + 22R_3$ isn't allowed, but $R_1 \to R_1 + \frac{22}{3} R_3$ is. You can add a scalar multiple of one row to another, but you can't just scale up a row.
In fact, the determinant on your second line is $27$ times the determinant on the first line.

The other issue was mentioned already by grand_chat, that you wrote a $2074$ where you meant $2072$. Other than these two mistakes, everything was correct.

However, the best method for solving this is undoubtedly to simplify the expression first, as I outlined above. This avoids arithmetic with large numbers where copying errors are more likely.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I'll try that!

Comment: using that method I get 4900, but I'm not sure why I don't get 4900 using the method posted originally. Any ideas on what went wrong?

Comment: @MathsHelp I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let use two fact

- $\det(A^T A) = \det(A)^2$
- det(A) doesn't change adding a scalar multiple of one column/row to another column/row, thus the expression can be simplified

Notably

$$det\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2&4\\1&-1&1&-3\\-2&3&7&-1\\4&6&2&8  \end{bmatrix}=det\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2&4\\0&-4&-1&-7\\-2&3&7&-1\\0&12&16&6  \end{bmatrix}=det\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2&4\\0&-4&-1&-7\\0&9&11&7\\0&12&16&6  \end{bmatrix}$$

then use Laplace on first column and

$$detA=det\begin{bmatrix}-4&-1&-7\\9&11&7\\12&16&6  \end{bmatrix}=70$$

Comment: That makes, sense, and 70x70 =4900 which is apparently correct on the online tool. But, aside from an error pointed out earlier (2072 instead of 2074), I'm not sure what's wrong with the method I used above. @gimusi

Comment: @MathsHelp indeed it is a good way to simplify, probably you made some mistake in calculation, of corse it is convenient work on detA!

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is *not* preserved when you do those transformation. Precisely, you're multiplying the determinant by $3^3$.

Indeed, if I ask Pari-GP to compute the determinant of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
896&1267&413\\
925&1274&460\\
1510&2072&760
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the answer is $-44100$. And
$$
\frac{(-3)(-44100)}{3^3}=4900
$$

As noted in comments you have mistakenly written $2074$ instead of $2072$.